# How to pass values inside array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've a array with this choices

```
    $choices = array(
        '-- Make a Selection --' => '',
        'Choice 1' => 'Choice 1',
        'Choice 2' => 'Choice 2',
        'Choice 3' => 'Choice 3',
        'Choice 4' => 'Choice 4',
        'Choice 5' => 'Choice 5'
    );
    return $choices;
```

The choices I need to populate with a custom field repeater (Advanced Custom Field)

```
if(have_rows('lista_de_variables')) : while(have_rows('lista_de_variables')) : the_row(); 

    $choice = get_sub_field('dimension');

endwhile; endif;

// this function returns an array of 
// label => value pairs to be used in
// a the select field
$choices = array(
    '-- Make a Selection --' => '',
    $choice => $choice,
);
return $choices;
```

Comment: Try using array_merge

Answer (score 0):

you should use the directly the field for the array

```
$choice = get_field('lista_de_variables');
print_r($choice);
```

For more information regarding the repeater field of acf you can 
Visit https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/print-repeater-array-values/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using

```
$choices = array(
    '-- Make a Selection --' => '',
    $choice => $choice,
);
```

you can simply use

```
$choices[$choice] = $choice;
```